# How to configure Select2MultipleWidget in Django

Tags: jquery, html, django, jquery-select2

I am trying to implement a Select2 Multi-select box in my Django project where a user can select from a range of interests and choose more than 1.

What is instead happening is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX4gk.png)

Where a user sees a scrollable list and can select one.

I am looking for this [example from Select2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCxGE.png)

Essentially I don't understand how to format the Select2 HTML code below into Django forms

```
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        ...
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
```

My code is below, I have omitted code that is not relevant. My scripts for JQuery etc are in my base.html file which include `Bootstrap, Js, Popper,js and JQuery`

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile
from django_select2.forms import Select2MultipleWidget

class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['interests']
        widgets = {
            'interests': Select2MultipleWidget,
        }
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

INTEREST_CHOICES = (
        ('FITNESS', 'Fitness'),
        ('SPIRITUAL', 'Spiritual'),
        ('VEGANISM', 'Veganism'),
        ('MOVIES', 'Movies'),
     )

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interests = MultiSelectField(choices = INTEREST_CHOICES)
```

profile.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}
{{ form.media.css }}

    {% block head %}
    <title>User profile</title>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onerror = function (msg) {
          $("body").attr("JSError", msg);
        }
    </script>

    {{ form.media.js }}

    <div class="container-fluid padding">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-lg-12 padding-success">
              <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  {{ p_form|crispy }}
                  <button type="submit" value="submit">Update Profile</button>
              </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am very grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: do you have django_select2 in installed_apps? My configuration looks similar to yours but mine works.